# "the most extreme."

Tags: phrase-meaning

The president cited Abbott's order which bars schools, governments and other jurisdictions from implementing mask mandates as **"the most extreme."**
Source: [USAToday](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/2021/08/03/get-out-of-the-way-biden-wades-into-state-level-fights-over-covid-measures/5473118001/)

What is the hidden words following the phrase "the most extreme"? Some possibilities that I've got for the time being:
(1) "the most extreme (anti-science behavior)"
(2) "the most extreme (wrongdoing)
(3) "the most extreme illegal measure"
(4) the most extreme bad health policy"

Which is correct? (4) cites Biden's comment "bad health policy" in the text that follows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammatically, it *seems* to be **order**, as that is the most recent word in the sentence that fits.

In reality, USAToday has altered the quote so that it will fit into their own sentence. According to [ABC News](https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/biden-governors-combatting-pandemic/story?id=79250169), here is what Biden actually said:

> In fact, **the most extreme** of these measures is in Texas where . . .

So the missing phrase is **of these measures,** which USAToday does not quote verbatim.

Newspaper articles are usually written in a hurry, and you cannot count on the authors getting everything right.

Answer (score 2):

He says it is the "most extreme order"

I can speculate on why the President thinks it is the most extreme order.  I suppose an order that, for example, "required schools to consult with parents before implementing mask mandates" would be less extreme.  An outright ban is the most extreme order of this type that Abbott could make.